# How to validate model attributes without using Data annotation in ASP.NET Core MVC

Tags: c#, validation, asp.net-core-mvc, model-validation

I want to validate models server-side in ASP.NET Core MVC:

```
public class Transaction
{
    [Key]
    public int Amount { get; set; }
    public int Account_Id { get; set; }
    public string Note { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
}
```

I want to validate these attributes... like `Amount` cannot have negative values. But I shouldn't use model validation and data annotations, like this:

```
[StringLength(100)]
public string Note { get; set; }
```

In ASP.NET Core MVC, where and how can I validate this?

Comment: You can do a direct value comparison on the property in your action. Nothing fancy. But you don't get the automatic messages and UI hints.

Comment: @jasen I can compare the value, but what if I wanted to make a field required?

Comment: Then stop processing the normal flow (don't commit to db, for instance) and return a message indicating the status.

Comment: Have a look at [Fluent Validation](https://docs.fluentvalidation.net/en/latest/aspnet.html). You declare the validation rules in a separate class to the model

Comment: Why you cannot use model validation?